# Is it ok to ask questions about scraping data from commercial websites?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can a user post a question about scraping data from a commercial website even if the specific website could be recognized from the sample html provided? Does it depend on the specific website's policy about scraping or does Stackoverflow have its own blanket policy for or against this type of question?
EDIT: To clarify, my question relates to potential data ownership issues.

Comment: Asking unique question is usually not a problem - do you have something specific in mind as an example (not one of "how to scrap dynamic site", "how to authenticate to …", "how to get page with curl/HttpClient/…", "how to parse HTML with regex"...)?

Comment: I have in mind a question about xpath expressions applied to a specific HTML fragment of a commercial website which could be recognized from that fragment

Comment: There are thousands questions on XPath... Since it sounds like you are not willing to create MCVE (which pretty much guarantees to remove any dependency/links to "commercial website" as side effect of minimizing the data) such SO post will collect downvotes due to lack of effort (and not some sort of police that this post seem to be asking / closed as duplicate)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the concept of MCVE which I was not familiar with.